# Akeneo missing files after installation process

Tags: apache, debian, akeneo

After successfully installing the dependencies for Akeneo and the Akeneo `pim-community-standard` on a Debian 9 machine, I can open the login screen in the frontend on `http://myhost.net/app.php`

The Login process throws a 404 error on `http://myhost.net/form/extensions`.
This should be a JSON file (like it is on the demo installation of Akeneo), but it was not built in the installation process. Also when I manually create this file the login process goes on to the next 404:

```
myhost.next/localization/format/date
myhost.next/rest/security/
myhost.next/rest/user/
```

Which part of the installation process is supposed to build these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://myhost.net/form/extensions` is a call to the Symfony backend so it's not a file to generate during installation.

The 404 error seems linked to the fact that you didn't activate mod_rewrite on your apache configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. mod_reqrite was on and correctly set up. But your answer made me check the vhost file configuration. There was a typo in the <Directory> path. Now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

I add my answer because I lost a lot of time. 
Solution for Digital Ocean server

Change vhost file to:

```
<VirtualHost your_server_ip>

     RewriteEngine On

     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/web/"

    <Directory /var/www/html/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted

        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options FollowSymlinks
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/web/bundles>
        RewriteEngine Off
    </Directory>


    SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/akeneo-pim_error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/akeneo-pim_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

edit your_server_ip
and load entering  ip in a browser (without /web/)